# Javascript XMLHTTPREQUEST Post sending GET on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest, localhost

I am trying to POST Form data using pure javascript XMLHTTPREQUEST library.  My javascript function first gets all the html form data and cleans it as well as check that it is the right format before sticking it in an Object. 
 Then the normal request library is used to send the `JSON.stringify(Object)` with the right headers.  The problem is I am testing it on my Apache localhost  and it does not send the data to the designated php file.  It only concatenates the data to my Url header as a GET request.

```
        let reqObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var elem = document.getElementById(msgContan);
        //add event listener for request
        reqObj.addEventListener("progress", function(eve) {
            if (eve.lengthComputable) {
                //show progress on download using view
                jsView.elementShowMover(elem, strPos,endPos,moveMs);
                document.getElementById(msgElemnt).innerText = Math.round(eve.loaded/eve.total * 100) + "% Complete";
            }
        });
        reqObj.addEventListener("load", function(eve) {
            if (reqObj.status >= 200 && reqObj.status < 300) {
                //elem.style.display = "none";
                console.log('Completed');
            }
        });
        reqObj.addEventListener("error", function(eve) {
            document.getElementById(msgElemnt).innerText = "Failed to post data.";
        });
        reqObj.addEventListener("abort", function(eve) {
            document.getElementById(msgElemnt).innerText = "Data post was cancelled.";
        });
        //set timeout @ 30 seconds
        reqObj.timeout = 30000;
        //open network request
        reqObj.open('POST', 'localhost/myprojects/pages/app/web_app/getter.php');
        //set http-headers
        reqObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //send the request
        reqObj.send(JSON.stringify(answ.jObj));
```

Can someone help to give me a clue why that would happen and how do you test a POST request on a localhost?

Comment: sounds like you are not cancelling the form submission

Comment: @epascarello Thanks.   How do I cancel form submission?

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: I believe I solved it.  You where right! I call the function with an `onclick` event bound to a html `<button>`.  The button had no `type` attribute set which meant it defaulted to `submit`.  I changed the button attribute to `type='button'` and for the first time it fired the `progress` event function to 100%.  The `load` event did not fire nor my php file.  But your diagnoses has lead to a cure and the POST request was sent.  I just have to figure out why the `load` event did not fire  and php file was not executed.  Thank you very much. Do you know the reason why this request act like this?

Comment: look at the network request and see what it shows

Comment: Thanks again.  You are quick and very well informed.  It shows `404 Not Found` with `Request URL:http://localhost/myprojects/pages/localhost/myprojects/pages/app/web_app/getter.php`.  Meaning my set httprequest send function should only be the url `app/web_app/getter.php` and not the one in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@epascarello gave the right diagnoses to solve my question.  Therefore I am posting it.
The concatenated data to my URL and constant GET request sent, even though `POST` was requested, is due to me

> not cancelling the form submission.

To cancel form submission depends on how the XmlHttpRequest object is called.  In my case I called the function with an `onclick` event bound to a html `<button>`.

> The button had no type attribute set which meant it defaulted to submit.

I changed the button attribute to `type='button'` which cancelled the form submission.
My second problem of not executing the php file or completing the request within the set javascript `load` event function was due to the XmlHttpRequest `.send` property's second parameter not set as a relative path.  My incorrect path therefore showed a

> network request

`404 Not Found` with `Request URL:http://localhost/myprojects/pages/localhost/myprojects/pages/app/web_app/getter.php`.
By changing my absolute path to a relative path the `POST` request was completed.